# Moving a RAID array from one SIL3114 controller to another?

Tags: raid, data-recovery, raid-0

I'm working with a machine that uses Asus A8N-SLI Premium motherboard, which has a Silicon Image 3114R RAID controller onboard and two drives in RAID-0 (why??!?!?).

The motherboard failed and I was wondering if tracking down a PCI RAID adapter with a 3114R controller to recover the array might work?

Update: I ended up moving the drives to a second computer and using Raid Reconstructor to move the data to a new hard drive but the advice below is sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should, just make sure that when you recreate the array that you also don't reinitialize it, otherwise that will wipe all of the data.

Comment: You do not need or want to recreate the array; it will simply be recognized when you plug the drives in.